# Question regarding DTFT of a complex signal

Tags: phase, dtft, complex

I have been doing DTFT practice problems for my DSP course, and I encountered this problem in the textbook that completely stumped me.

[image]

The question asks to find the DTFT of the shown signal and to plot its magnitude and phase. I am very comfortable with doing this with real-valued signals, but have no idea where to start when it comes to complex signals. Especially how the plotting would be done. I would appreciate any advice on how to tackle the problem.

Comment: HINT: Complex numbers are **numbers** too. In exactly the same way that you say $u=2$ and $v = 4 \cdot u$, you can also say $u = 4 + 5j$ and $v = 8j \cdot u$. All operations are also defined over complex numbers. So, all that you have to do here is run your numbers through the sums. HINT2: This waveform has a particularly useful characteristic when it comes to the DFT.

Comment: it's simpler than a "complex" number.  it's purely imaginary.  just factor out the $j$.

Comment: Look up the definition of a linear operator.  The DTFT is one.

Comment: So my representation of the signal is the following: j*del[n] -j*del[n-4]. Is this the correct representation? From here, I will factor the j and apply the DTFT as it is a linear operator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you almost have the solution. As you suggest in your comment, if you express your signal as :
$$
x(n) = j\cdot \delta(n) - j\cdot \delta(n-4)
$$
As DFT is linear, you will get :
$$
\begin{align}
X(k) &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x(n)\cdot e^{-2j\pi \frac{kn}{N}}\\
 &= j\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\delta (n)\cdot e^{-2j\pi \frac{kn}{N}} - j\cdot \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\delta (n-4)\cdot e^{-2j\pi \frac{kn}{N}}\\
&=j-j\cdot e^{-8j\pi \frac{k}{N}}\\
&=\text{ }...
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer Frank, I think you misread my question about DTFT as being DFT. I was able to use the same logic to get to the final answer, thanks.